# Magento - Creating tabs on home page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, magento

Is there a way to create tabs on home page? If yes can some one let me know how to do that and how to put that code in CMS>>Home Page>>Content section?

Cheers

Comment: What are the tabs used for? What you want is something like jQuery Tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ -- This will allow you to create specific markup on the content section, and you can easily put the Javascript in the cms layout file.

Comment: I agree with @ZacharySchuessler.  You can use any Tabs code that you like.  To populate the tabs, use Custom Attributes and call them in the tabs with this code:  `echo $_product->getAttributeText('your_code');` or `$_product->getYourCode()` where "YourCode" is a camel-case version of your attribute code, in this example it would be `your_code`

Comment: I would like to show mostly viewed products, best selling product in tabs on my Home page. @ZacharySchuessler: I did see your link but dint get the code to put into CMS Page content section. Could you actually help in posting thru means of a sample code as to what code needs to be put in, to view, say 'mostly viewed products' on home page in form of a tab

Comment: The examples should be good enough, and if you are indeed using the jQuery solution you will need to add your jQuery script in noConflict mode. Show us that you have tried to do this yourself and we can take another look. All of this is easily found on SO and Google.